# Need Help Writing a multiple program installer that gets installer from a webserver

Tags: deployment, installation, windows-installer, nsis, java-web-start

Okay, I am trying to write an installer that installs multiple programs.  The installer needs to be able to either get the files from a web server, or be able to package the files into a single installer file.

The end result I am looking for is a user hits a webpage, they can click a link to download a single installer file and the installer goes ahead and installs each of the programs.  Quiet installations would be preferable but not absolutely necessary. I am trying to make this as user friendly and idiot proof as possible.

Grabbing the installers for each program from a web server would be preferable so it always grabs the latest version and I will not have to tweak the installer script each time the programs are updated.

I have looked into NSIS and MSI, and neither seem to be able to do what I need.  I have entertained the idea of using Java Web Start to run a Java program that can install everything, but I am not sure the plausibility of that.  If that is possible, then the user would not even need to run a file the Java Web Start would just take care of everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps [Ninite](http://ninite.com/) will help.

If not, there are two possible solutions:

1. You can try using a MSI wrapper which installs the applications as prerequisites or through custom actions. It's dirty and complicated, but MSI is a standard.
2. You can write your own application which handles the installers. This is most likely the best approach.

Comment: I looked at ninite originally, but I need to be able to install programs that they do not offer.  From what I could tell Ninite is not open source so I couldn't roll my own version to use the installers that I have.